# Dispatcher for an akka actor/router

Tags: akka

I have the following config

```
akka{
  actor {

    deployment{
       /my-router {
           dispatcher = akka.actor.my-dispatcher
           router = round-robin-pool
           nr-of-instances = 100
           cluster {
              enabled = on
              max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 30
           }
       }         
    }

    my-dispatcher {
       type = Dispatcher
       executor = "fork-join-executor"
       fork-join-executor {
           parallelism-min = 4
           parallelism-factor = 2.0
           parallelism-max = 20
       }
   }
  }
```

}

I've found(with help of visualVM) that there are no threads of `my-dispatcher` used. However, if I specify `my-dispatcher` via `.withDispatcher("akka.actor.my-dispatcher")` when I create props for my router via FromConfig I can observe that threads. I can state that I observe those threads because I see threads with name like this: `actorSystenName-akka.actor.my-dispatcher-8`

So questions are:

1. How to set dispatcher for a router via config?
2. Will this dispatcher be used for routees(that are obviously childs of a      router)?
3. What are the differences between specifying dispatcher via config and via withDispatcher?
4. I've also tried to surround config's dispatcher setting in `""`, but still didn't observe threads in visualVM with dispatcher's name, so do threads' names have such pattern `{actorSystenName}-{dispatcher}-{number}`?

**EDIT**
I've found that `pool-dispatcher` property can be used for setting router's dispatcher for children(routees). But `FromConfig` which extends `Pool` lacks overriding of `usePoolDispatcher` method. So 1 more question: is this made(`usePoolDispatcher` is not overriden in `FromConfig`) intentioally or `FromConfig` is not designed for such usage?